# Add search filter to my listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

Good evening,
It's true that I have found some tutorial on creating a search bar for ListView. Among those that I followed is: [Android Adding Search Functionality to ListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/). The code works fine but I can not adapt it to my list. I had to restart my project from the beginning because I messed. I am a beginner in Android programming and really need help. Here is my code:
ShoppingListActivity.java

```
public class ShoppingListActivity extends Activity {

 private List<Produit> mCartList;
 private ProduitAdapter mProductAdapter;
 EditText inputSearch;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.shoppinglist);


  mCartList = ShoppingListHelper.getCartList();

  // Make sure to clear the selections
  for(int i=0; i<mCartList.size(); i++) {
   mCartList.get(i).selected = false;
  }


  // Create the list
  final ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
  mProductAdapter = new ProduitAdapter(mCartList, getLayoutInflater(), true);
  listViewCatalog.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

  inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

  inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { 
            String text = inputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            mProductAdapter.filter(text);}
    });


  listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
     long id) {
    Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ProduitDetailsActivity.class);
    productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingListHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX, position);
    startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
   }
  });

 }
```

and this is what contains ShoppingListHelper.java :

```
public static List<Produit> getCatalog(Resources res){
     if(catalog == null) {
      catalog = new Vector<Produit>();
      catalog.add(new Produit("Nutella", res
        .getDrawable(R.drawable.nutella),
        "Pate à tartiner au chocolat, au bon goût de noisettes", 750));
     }

     return catalog;
    }
```

And ProduitAdapter.java

```
     public class ProduitAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


 private List<Produit> mProductList;
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;
 private boolean mShowQuantity;


 private ArrayList<Produit> arraylist;
 public ProduitAdapter(List<Produit> list, LayoutInflater inflater, boolean showQuantity) {
  mProductList = list;
  mInflater = inflater;
  mShowQuantity = showQuantity;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return mProductList.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return mProductList.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }


 public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        mProductList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            mProductList.addAll(arraylist);
        } 
        else 
        {
            for (Produit wp : arraylist) 
            {
                if (wp.getProduct().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).startsWith(charText)) 
                {
                    mProductList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I use eclipse JUNO.

EDITED:
As you see in my code I've implemented a filter but my editText don't work! in compilation no errors shown!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your link in question is broken.
You haven't added any log messages of problem nor what the real problem is, and your code isn't complete.

Comment: this is the link : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: Ok, but your problems isn't yet clarified. what difficulty do you have?

Comment: After long search and changes in my android project, I want to add a filter search to my listview but I don't know how to do it!

Comment: post your full code and you will have more chance of getting an answer.

Comment: EDITED take a look please